# Pydev: IPython is NOT available after Adding src folder to PYTHONPATH

Tags: eclipse, ipython, pydev

I'm using Eclipse kepler & pydev 3.4.1 on Ubuntu 12.04.

I installed ipython 0.12.1 via pip, which was located in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/, so I added this path to PYTHONPATH via eclipse->preference->PyDev->Interpreters->Python Interpreter->System PYTHONPATH.

By this way, I would start IPython in the interactive console(just press CTRL_ALT_ENTER), the output is :

> Python 2.7.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 20:00:17)  Type "copyright",
>   "credits" or "license" for more information.
>
> IPython 0.12.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. ?         ->
>   Introduction and overview of IPython's features. %quickref -> Quick
>   reference. help      -> Python's own help system. object?   -> Details
>   about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
>
> PyDev -- Python IDE for Eclipse For help on using PyDev's Console see
>   http://pydev.org/manual_adv_interactive_console.html

It looks fine, but when I try to run a simple code in the interactive console, say:

```
from common_function import *
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("hello")
```

It shows me an ImportError:

> File "/git/mycode/python_lab/pylab/simple_test.py", line 7, in 
>   from common_function import *
>   ImportError: No module named common_function

Here, the simple_test.py and common_function.py are placed in the same src folder, and I find some posts on stackoverflow saying that adding the src folder which contatins all the py files to project's PYTHONPATH would solve this problem, so I tried and it did solve the ImportError, but the IPython is disable, the output of interactive console is :

> /usr/bin/python2.7 2.7.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 20:00:17) [GCC 4.6.3]
>   PyDev console: using default backend (IPython not available).
>   runfile('/media/data/yanglin/local/work/git/mycode/python_lab/pylab/simple_test.py')
>
> hello

Any one know how to fix this problem?